# How to debug 'detected unhandled Python exception in' /var/log/messages

Tags: python

I have a python script checking status of my web service schedules for let's say 2000 times. One check takes like 5 minutes so the script execution takes like 2000x5 minutes.

I have application logs set up by **logger** and my **system logs** just to log information what is going on while script is running. However, script stops from some reasons. There is no single entry in my customized logs. The only thing I can find is

```
less /var/log/messages


 cat /var/log/messages | grep --color "pycharm.py"
Mar 27 08:48:48 hostname python: detected unhandled Python exception in 'pycharm.py'
Mar 30 13:58:16 hostname python: detected unhandled Python exception in 'pycharm.py'
Mar 31 08:22:01 hostname python: detected unhandled Python exception in 'pycharm.py'
Apr  1 05:42:09 hostname python: detected unhandled Python exception in 'pycharm.py'
Apr  2 03:04:16 hostname python: detected unhandled Python exception in 'pycharm.py'
```

The environment is Red Hat 7.2

Can anyone suggest to add some lines to script to chatch errors.

Things like do not give me anything.

```
try: 
   command
except:
   smth
```

Answer (score 0):

You should log the unhandled exception as well as its stack trace, so you know what when wrong and where.

Use `logger.exception()` to log the exception content and stack trace.